# Peering of ISPs

Tags: bgp, isp, peering

How does having multiple peers affect an ISPs performance?

If I have 2 option of ISPs to select from, where ISP1 has only 2 peers and ISP2 has 10 peers, which one should I select?

Or does number of peers even matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A larger number of peers basically means that the ISP is better connected - more efficient and possibly more redundant.

However, the pure figure doesn't tell you everything. It's also about the quality of those peerings (bandwidth, redundancy, capabilities and size of peer/carrier, ...).

Comment: Please upvote the question